# C++ idiomatic way of iterating over a container that itself is being modified

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration

I find myself iterating over a container X that is being modified inside the loop. But in each iteration, the unmodified X is needed:

```
for (int x : X) { // wrong, container X in iteration should be the "original"
    modify_X();  // X modified here
}
```

A solution is to iterate over a copy

```
containerT X_copy(X);
for (int x : X_copy) {
    modify_X();   
}
```

or

```
for (int x : containerT {X}) {
    modify_X();   
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: I think the second option is as idiomatic as you can get.

Comment: Unless your container holds pointers, none of these modify the original.

Comment: Need more meat in the example to give a conclusive answer

Comment: unless you are explicitly working with pointers , `x` will be a copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last example in your question looks the simplest. However, from C++20, you could also do this:

```
for (auto copy = X; int i : copy)
{
  modify_X();
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Gfvv5).

Note that in your first snippet, it's not only logically wrong, but it also invokes undefined behavior, as you are modifying a range that you're iterating over.

Comment: oh thats great, the kind of syntax i was hoping for!! must say that these language updates *do* improve syntax:-)

Comment: @zen They do, but in this case it's accidental. The purpose of this construct is when you want to iterate like this: `for (int i : f().X)`, where `f()` returns a temporary object with an `X` member. But it can be adapted to other cases, of course :)