# idiomatic way of changing container elements while iterating over the container

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

Is the following way of manipulating a string or a container idiomatic?

```
string s = "hello";
for (auto &p : s) {
    p = somefunction(p); // somefunction without side effects
}
```

This implies iterating over a range while changing the contained elements. The container is not modified in its layout so the iterators should be valid during the iteration.

The same effect could of course easily "be coded" differently, but I am interested in if this is the idiomatic way of doing it?

I asked a similar question earlier, but that was related to the case where the container's layout is being modified, and here the answer is: iterate over a copy of the container.
[C++ idiomatic way of iterating over a container that itself is being modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376590/c-idiomatic-way-of-iterating-over-a-container-that-itself-is-being-modified)

Comment: Idioms can change. It really depends on the specific use case. e.g. here I would simply write `s = std::string(5, 'a');`

Comment: yeah, this is a minimal example, in reality 'a' can vary during the loop. just wanted to make the code hyper simple. maybe i over-did it...

Comment: Kind of. The thing is, "how 'a' varies in the loop", will inform the kind of code that would be easy to read. Like I said, it depends on what the code is actually supposed to do.

Comment: yeah, changed the assignment from ```= 'a'``` to ```= somefunction(p)```

Comment: This is probably as idiomatic as it gets with the exception of  a vector of booleans (which is really not a container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idioms can change over time, so here's a C++20 version that might very well become idiomatic in the not too distant future.

```
std::ranges::transform(s, s.begin(), someFunction);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gn46ar).

Comment: absolutely! thx! but lets make that ```s.begin()``` optional now that we're at it;-)

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised Actually, I expect we will soon enough. In C++23, it's likely that we'll be able to do something like `s |= std::action::transform(someFunction);` which would be *really* nice :)